# REST api call between two pods in minikube

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, devops, minikube

I'm running a REACT application on top of a minikube cluster which includes frontend and the backend in the same namespace `default`. When frontend send a request to backend, request doesn't reach to the backend. Load balancing happens via `ingress-nginx`.

service for front end...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: frontend-panel
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

Service for backend

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: backend-panel
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

Front end is a react application which calls different services which run in side of the same minikube cluster..,
Configfile of react.

```
window.config = {
  backend: {
    backend_service: "http://backend-service:8080/"
  }
}
```

Result of `kubectl describe svc backend-service`.

```
Name:              backend-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       Selector:  app=backend-panel
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.106.135.236
Port:              <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.10:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Other than `"http://backend-service:8080/"` I tried `"http://backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/"`. But without failing the request it hangs for a longtime.

Comment: share output of kubectl describe svc backend-service. Does it work if you use `PODIP:8080` ?

Comment: If you use `172.17.0.10:8080` does it work? Can you port forward to the pod using `kubectl port forward`?

Comment: Port forwarding is for access pods from localhost right? But in here pods need communicate between them, inside of the cluster.

Comment: are able to curl 172.17.0.10:8080 from another pod within the cluster? You have an ingress between the frontend and backend?

Comment: There is no ingress between frontend and backend

Comment: Your services are correct and the endpoint is being recognized. Have you tested using the IP as @ArghyaSadhu suggested? We have to make sure it's not a DNS problem, so please try to `curl 172.17.0.10:8080`.

Comment: Curl worked. It returns success message. But I cannot ping to another pod using ping. When ping called it hangs

Comment: @mWatney When used `172.17.0.10:8080` Instead of `backend-service:8080` it works.. What could be the issue here?

Comment: It means your pod is listening on the right port. Now run the same test on `10.106.135.236:8080` so we can make sure your service is also working.

Comment: @mWatney when I change it to `10.106.135.236:8080` freezes...

Comment: How are you testing it? Directly from the react app? Have you tested it in another minikube? Have you considered running `minikube delete` and start fresh? I reproduced a similar scenario and for me it works as designed.

Comment: First I used `curl`, if it's work then change the configs in react. That's where it freeze

Comment: So it seems like the kubernetes part of it is working. I can't help you with react as I don't  know much about it. What I can suggest you is to create a new question more focused on the react part of the problem to get attention from react masters.

Answer (score 0):

Service looks good because it has got POD IP and PORT as `Endpoints`. Verify if you are able to access the pod directly via PODIP and PORT using `curl 172.17.0.10:8080` from another pod in the cluster. If that does not work then there could be two reasons

1. Application is not listening on port `8080`. Just specifying `containerPort: 8080` in pod yaml does not make the application listen on port `8080`.
2. Application is listening on `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I can curl into `172.17.0.10:8080` frontend to backend without any problem. But problem is when the call happens via react

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the IP address of minikube.
Just do minikube ip in the powershell to get the IP address